# "Dependency could not be resolved" deploying ASP.NET 5 website to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2015

I have a ASP.NET 5 website with 3 subprojects. The subprojects have a reference to EF 6.1. Locally everything works fine, but when I try to deploy the website to azure using the assistant, I get the error message

> Dependency EntityFramework >= 6.1.3 could not be resolved in
>   XXX\wrap\PDWeb.Application\project.json   22

The generated project.json of the PDWeb.Application subproject is

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../Application/PDWeb.Application/PDWeb.Application.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../Application/PDWeb.Application/obj/{configuration}/PDWeb.Application.dll",
        "pdb": "../../Application/PDWeb.Application/obj/{configuration}/PDWeb.Application.pdb"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "PDWeb.Model": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "net45": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../src/Application/PDWeb.Application/PDWeb.Application.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../src/Application/PDWeb.Application/obj/{configuration}/PDWeb.Application.dll",
        "pdb": "../../src/Application/PDWeb.Application/obj/{configuration}/PDWeb.Application.pdb"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "PDWeb.Model": "1.0.0-*",
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "PDWeb.Services": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The complete build output can be found [here](http://esf-server.de/downloads/buildoutput.txt)

Comment: The error also occurs when I try to deploy locally to filesystem...

Comment: I have still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by converting my subprojects to ***.xproj**...

Comment: How you can convert EF6 project to .xproj ?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same issue, when I tried to publish my dnx project.
I run "dnu restore" in every subfolder into the wrap folder and the problem was solved.

In your solution folder is a wrap folder. In this folder are subfolders with project.json files. Open command prompt, go to every subfolder and execute "dnu restore"

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?