# vNext beta6 deployment error - The dependency EntityFramework >= 6.1.2 could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

After updating to beta6, I got the latest tools and ran wrap against my two 4.5 projects and the project.json is generated correctly in the wrap directory.  The solution compiles and runs fine after my updates.

However, when I try to deploy the website, I get the error that EntityFramework cannot be resolved and the error points to the project.json file in the wrap directory.

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627463/dependency-could-not-be-resolved-deploying-asp-net-5-website-to-azure), but changing to xproj is not an option/answer for me. This was all deploying without the error under beta4.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and after a bit of research it appears to be a tooling bug that affects VS2015 REL + beta5 and as of this writing appears to not have been fixed in later betas as well. Manually running dnu restore from the project root cleared the errors for me.